# Add an application to the command search path in csh

Tags: path, profile, csh

Recently, I have installed an application (gnuplot) under user directory (/home/usr/bin). I want to run the application whenever I type 'gnuplot' in any directory. What could I do?

I tried to set the path in ~/.cshrc by

```
setenv gnuplot /home/usr/bin/gnuplot
```

but it doesn't work. It reports "command not found" as I type gnuplot in the terminal.

Comment: `/home/usr`, really? That's insane. `/usr/local` or `/opt/usr` is where things like this should go.

Answer (score 3):

You should add this directory to the PATH variable. in C shell this can be done with command:

```
setenv PATH $PATH:/home/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several choices.
The first two options works only with one user. The third and fourth options works for all users.

#### Alias

Add this line in your `.cshrc`:
`alias gnuplot '/home/usr/bin/gnuplot'`

---

#### Update PATH

Add this line in your `.cshrc`:
`setenv PATH $PATH:/home/usr/bin`

---

#### Update /etc/csh.cshrc

The file `/etc/csh.cshrc` is read by all CSH instance. You can either create an alias, either update the `$PATH` environment variable. Same syntax as previous options.

---

#### Link to global path

Assuming all users have access to `/usr/bin/`, create a link to `gnuplot`:
`$> ln -s /home/usr/bin/gnuplot /usr/bin/gnuplot`

Comment: That `$PATH` should not include the `gnuplot` binary itself.

Comment: On RedHat and Fedora systems and others, application-specific settings should/can be placed in `/etc/profile.d`, in this case, `/etc/profile.d/gnuplot.csh` _and_ `/etc/profile.d/gnuplot.sh`

Comment: @Pl4nk , what are the pros and cons of using Alias vs. adding the program's directory to your PATH? I have to do this for a bunch of utility commands, each in their own directory.